# How to use twitter search API asynchronously in python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, oauth, twitter, tornado

I read the book [Introduction to Tornado](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021292.do). It introduces the asynchronous feature of tornado in an application using twitter search API.

The [code](https://github.com/Introduction-to-Tornado/Introduction-to-Tornado/blob/master/asynchronous_web_services/async_http/tweet_rate_gen.py) is as follows:

```
class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
     @tornado.web.asynchronous
     @tornado.gen.engine
     def get(self):
        query = self.get_argument('q')
        client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
        response = yield tornado.gen.Task(client.fetch,
            "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?" + \
            urllib.urlencode({"q": query, "result_type": "recent", "rpp": 100}))
        ...
        self.finish()
```

It uses the v1 twitter API to search a keywork. However, the new [v1.1 twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets) forbids the use of non oauth request. As a result, I have to use the oauth library with my consumer key and access key to request the twitter search API.

```
def request_twitter(url, http_method = 'GET', post_body = '', http_headers = ''):
    consumer = oauth.Consumer(key = consumer_key, secret = consumer_secret)
    token = oauth.Token(key = access_token, secret = access_secret)
    client = oauth.Client(consumer, token) 
    request = client.request(url, method = http_method, body = post_body, headers = http_headers)
    return request
```

But the oauth client doesn't provide the asynchronous way to request. So I want to know how can I make the asynchronous request using oauth client to twitter API in python? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [TwitterMixin](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/auth.html#twitter) that is supplied with Tornado and study [its code](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/auth.html#TwitterMixin) a bit.