# How to stop celery task while it is being executed and continue the execution after some time?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, celery

I have the following celery task(simplified), which interacts with Twitter API.

```
@app.task
def get_followers(screen_name, **kwargs):
    cursor = kwargs.get('cursor', -1)
    followers = kwargs.get('followers', [])
    while True:
        response = twitter_api.call('followers', 'ids', screen_name=screen_name, cursor=cursor)
        if response.status_code == '429': # RATE LIMIT EXCEEDED
            # do something here

        cursor = response.json()['next_cursor']
        if cursor == 0: # we're done
            break
    return followers
```

I want to be able to pause task for some time when the rate limit is hit, and resume the execution from the point where it left off. (Or throw an error and retry the task, passing in additional kwargs). How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Check this: http://python-twitter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rate_limits.html

Comment: And this: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting

Comment: @mohammad-yusuf-ghazi I know about these pages, I'm interested specifically in the celery part here. As far as I understand,  if I have `sleep_on_rate_limit=True` and the rate limit is exceeded, the task is just going to "hang in there", consuming space in the worker pool for the next 15 minutes, is it not?

Comment: You will have to make asynchronous calls to the api then. Check the links on this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668895/how-to-use-twitter-search-api-asynchronously-in-python

Comment: @mohammad-yusuf-ghazi sorry, but I don't see how this is related to my question. I have a problem with the celery task, not with API calls.  And besides, I use django and not tornado (which is mentioned only in the tags section of the question, but it should be irrelevant to the _hypothetical_ solution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just retry your task when you catch a 429 error code :

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def get_followers(self, screen_name, **kwargs):
    cursor = kwargs.get('cursor', -1)
    followers = kwargs.get('followers', [])
    while True:
        response = twitter_api.call('followers', 'ids', screen_name=screen_name, cursor=cursor)
        if response.status_code == '429': 
            # RATE LIMIT EXCEEDED
            self.retry(countdown=15*60)

        cursor = response.json()['next_cursor']
        if cursor == 0: # we're done
            break
    return followers
```

Note that I added `bind=True` in your task decorator and `self` as parameter in the definition of your task to be able to do `self.retry` when you get a 429.

in `retry` use the argument `countdown` to say when you want the task to be retried (in seconds). Here I chose 15min (twitter API rate limits)

You can find more infos about retrying in the celery documentation :

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#retrying